# Non hamiltonian cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonicity

It is known that almost all cubic graphs are hamiltonian ([see here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1002/rsa.3240030202))

However, I did not find any information about non-hamiltonian cubic graphs online. If you know some properties/literature about non-hamiltonian cubic graphs I would appreciate if you let me know. More specifically, the question that interests me is how the cubic graphs that are not Hamiltonian are different from Hamiltonian cubic graphs (what properties do they have that makes them not Hamiltonian)?

Comment: It's useful to consider some exmples. Try to draw a cubic graph with a bridge (i.e., an edge whose removal makes the graph disconnected).

Comment: I was thinking more about "if and only if" direction. For sure if we have a bridge, we can not have a Hamiltonian cycle. But it does not work the other way around and I am more interested in the other direction.. For instance, Petersen graph does not have a bridge but still does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: the problem seems to me rather intriguing (actually, I worked on a related problem this summer). One way to think about it "from scratch" is that all cubic hamiltonian graphs can be obtained by adding $n$ chords to the $2n$-cycle.